# Java Class confusion?

Tags: java

I have a class called user that contains the the two variables name and age.

```
package test;

public class user {
String name;
int age;

}
```

Then in my main.java i'm creating an array of that class type.

```
package test;
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    user[] array = new user[2];
    array[0].name = "ryan";
    array[0].age = 18;
    array[1].name ="Ryan";
    array[1].age = 17;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i].name);
        System.out.println(array[i].age);
    }
    }
}
```

However i get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.main.main(main.java:5)
```

Any help?

Comment: You need to create a new user for each slot of the array. `array[0] = new user()`. Creating a box that can contains balls doesn't means that there is balls inside.

Comment: Please follow [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) and start your class names with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions to write class names with a capital letter (here user- and main-class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user[] array = new user[2];
```

is just a definition of array but the elements of arrays are NOT initialized/are NULL. Hence accessing an attribute or method will result in `NullPointerException`. You should initialize array element before using them, like this:

```
array[0] = new user();
array[1] = new user();
```

Answer (score 2):

References are initialized to `null` by default in Java - [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> For all reference types [(§4.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3), the default value is null.

So writing `array[0].name = "ryan";` is like writing `null.name = "ryan";` which causes the *exception*.

You should *initialize* each object in the array. Also please follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) and change `user` to `User`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make "new" objects too. Only the array is not sufficient

Answer (score 1):

You created only place for two `User`s. Write:

array[0] = new User();

And your example will work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User[] array = new User[2];

    array[0] = new User();       
    array[0].name = "ryan";
    array[0].age = 18;

    array[1] = new User(); 
    array[1].name ="Ryan";
    array[1].age = 17;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i].name);
        System.out.println(array[i].age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no object to assign a value to at

```
 array[0].name = "ryan";
```

All you have is an array of variables that nothing has been assigned to as yet.  You need to create one first for each address in the array...

```
 array[0] = new user();
```

then set it's name.

Also, class names should be uppercase `User`, not `user`

Lastly, if you are stepping through an array you are better to use it's size rather than a hard coded number

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

Better yet, do a for-each

```
 for (user u : array)  //for each user in array
 {
  System.out.println(u.name);
  System.out.println(u.age);
 }
```